# PL/pgSQL If Exists Display the result without a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I have a statement here that runs fine from what I can tell. If evaluates the condition and sticks the result into a variable. All I need to know is how to read the value out of the variable and display it. Thanks

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE result text;

BEGIN
IF EXISTS (select 1 from siteName where SiteNameID=9) THEN
   SELECT 'Yes' into result;
ELSE 
   SELECT 'No' into result;
END IF;

END
$do$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return data from a `DO` command. For that, you would need a function. With `DO` commands you are restricted to messages from `RAISE` like Denis provided, or you can write data to tables or temp tables, and select from them.

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
CREATE TEMP TABLE site9_exists AS
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sitename WHERE sitenameid=9) AS result;
END
$do$;

SELECT result FROM site9_exists;
```

Of course, you wouldn't need the `DO` command at all for the trivial example ...

Answer (score 1):

In the event that by display, you meant output to STDOUT:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'result: %', result;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

A DO-statement can't return anything. You could use a notice, like Denis already showed.

But why do you need a function? You could use a normal query for this, something like this:

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN input.SiteNameID = siteName.SiteNameID THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS result
FROM    (SELECT 9 AS SiteNameID) input
    LEFT JOIN siteName ON input.SiteNameID = siteName.SiteNameID;
```

(not tested....)